# Extension of duration of @90days tourist visa (multiple entry-1yr)

Tags: india

I have a 1 year mutilple entry tourist visa for India which allows me a maximum stay of 90 days. About 1 month after I reached India, I have secured a 3 month training at PGI. Now the total duration of my stay here will be around 4.5 months. How I can stay for an extended period and what will be the procedure to extend my visa to enable me to complete my training course?

Comment: Where are we, Japan? Close voting as 'unclear'

Comment: If you have a tourist visa then I think you are violating its conditions by attending a training course. I expect the institute will not let you attend the course without the requisite visa anyways.

Comment: @GayotFow “visa for India […] I reached India”. How is *that* unclear?

Comment: wrong reason for closing, this should go to expats, I think.

Comment: RedBaron already nailed it, but it comes worse. Visas are limited in time because the country issuing it want to make sure they decide if they want you to stay or not.  Because you *knew* that your stay is limited and you *still* tried to attend a course which will cause an overstay, they very, very probably *will* kick you out. The best thing you can do is to cancel immediately your course if you do not want to barred forever in India.

Answer (score 2):

You have a tourist visa, the standard 180-day visa with multiple entry, and participating in a training program is not allowed on that visa. That would require issuance of a new visa, for which you would have to exit and reenter the country.

India is extremely stringent with visa extensions. The rare  exceptions are those granted to individuals of Indian origin, or those who encounter an emergency (medical, stolen passport and, in it, the visa needed to exit). Changing the purpose of your stay in India would not be considered a valid reason.

You can ask about a 14-day extension at the [Ministry of Home Affairs](http://www.mha.nic.in/) in Delhi, 26 Jaisalmer House, Man Singh Rd, 011-23385748 boihq@mha.nic.in

Another alternative is the Foreigners’ Regional Registration Office, Level 2, East Block 8, Sector 1, Rama Krishna Puram, Delhi, 011-26195530 ffrodli@nic.in

While there are [FRRO regional offices](http://boi.gov.in/content/frro-contact-list), it appears that smaller, local authorities are much less likely to entertain such requests.

Edit: @DJClayworth contributed an important note:

> Just to point out to OP what I hope is obvious, if you have already started your training with your current visa, you are breaking the law.

Comment: Just to point out to OP what I hope is obvious, if you have already started your training with your current visa **you are breaking the law**.